# Exporting a VueJs project as a component

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I've been working on a VueJs project which uses the VueX store as well - Now I plan on exporting this as a package so that it can be integrated within other websites as well - The problem is with the VueX store; As the other websites will have their own store, is it possible to import another child store into it? (child store = my component's store) - If so, how should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverflow!

If your Vue library uses the VuexStore, you have to ensure that the user has Vuex installed and enabled. You can achieve this by installing your library from a [Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin). This way, you can have an entry point in your lib that receive a `context` object, including the user's Vuex store instance.

Then, you can register your module using `store.registerModule('mymodule', myModuleObj)`.

Here is an article that might help you: https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-part-2-c92a42af84e9